# Why Cannot I Delete Comments From Evince-pdfs?

Tags: 20.04, evince

I made several comments in a pdf in evince, and I would like to remove some of them.

I thought this would by straight-forward by going to the comment and clicking the "Delete" key on my keyboard, but apparently not. Right-clicking on a comment shows a menu, but there is no appropriate command for deleting the comments either.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I mean this by comment:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by comments? I'm only able to add annotations... which can easily be removed.

Comment: I edited my question. Please elaborate on how you can easily remove the annotations/comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the annotation then click "Remove annotation".

[image]